# WSO2 API Manager 2.6

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

We are updating our WSO2 API Manager from version 2.1 to version 2.6.
We are using a distributed deployment (Pattern 4) with Puppet support.
Reading the update guide (https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release) we are noticing it talks only about database upgrade and artifact updates.
What about all the remaining configurations?

It seems we should install a new distributed environment (ver 2.6) and configure it again from the ground. 
In this case, we would like to use Puppet.
Anyway, Puppet files (ver. 2.6) don't have hiera configuration files as it happened in version 2.1, so I'm wondering how to add configuration parameters.

Moreover, in the puppet files I can't find any cluster configuration parameters.

What's the best way to upgrade our distributed environment from 2.1 to 2.6?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you will have to do the configurations again once the database and the resource migration is done.

Regarding the puppet scripts, hope you saw this repo https://github.com/wso2/puppet-apim/tree/v2.6.0.1 . configuration parameters are set in the https://github.com/wso2/puppet-apim/blob/v2.6.0.1/modules/apim/manifests/params.pp